# get data from fragments to the other class

Tags: android, xamarin, android-fragments, xamarin.android

I'm new in xamarin android. I have a fragment that comes up every time. Inside it i have a variable id which i need and i don't know how to get it. When someone scan his card i get ID but full operation is inside that fragment.

here's code from Activity:

```java
if (savedInstanceState == null)
{
    FragmentTransaction transaction = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
    var fragment = new CardReaderFragment();
    transaction.Replace(Resource.Id.sample_content_fragment, fragment);
    transaction.Commit();

}
```

And code from that fragment where i have "card_account_field" and i need it in my other class.

```java
if (v != null)
{
    mAccountField = (TextView)v.FindViewById(Resource.Id.card_account_field);
    mCardReader = new CardReader(new WeakReference<CardReader.AccountIdCard>(this));
    // Disable Android Beam and register our card reader callback
    EnableReaderMode();
}
```

i just need get `mAccountField` and use it in my `MainActivity` but that variable is inside fragment box. Can i somehow pass its value out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ISharedPreferences` to achieve it

In the fragment, when you get the ID.You can use `ISharedPreferences` to store it.

```
            ISharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences(Application.Context);
            ISharedPreferencesEditor editor = prefs.Edit();
            editor.PutString("ID", "12345");
            // editor.Commit();    // applies changes synchronously on older APIs
            editor.Apply();        // applies changes asynchronously on newer APIs
```

Then you can get the ID whatever you want.

```
 ISharedPreferences prefs1 = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences(Application.Context);
          string  myID = prefs1.GetString("ID", "1");
```